# C++ support on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've installed Visual Studio Code and a number of plugins for C++ development (C/C++, CMake, Doxygen, LLDB Debugger) but I can't seem to make this work. I can't refactor, auto-complete has no clue where to look for options and syntax highlight could be much better.

Are there any configuration options I'm missing or is this just a glorified text editor?

Comment: Most likely you mistake `Visual Studio Code` for "real" `Visual Studio`.

Comment: According to the marketing you get most of the IDE goodies if it's configured correctly. Never used it so I have no idea how to configure it. I see a buttload of configuration options though. If you add your config file to the question odds are much better that someone can spot anything you've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is a Text Editor, which is available on Windows, Linux, and OSX. It has several plugins which allow you to get some cool features, you can find a lot of documentation online.

Visual Studio (or Visual C++) is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). It is available on Windows and on OSX (for C# only for now if I remember). It provides a lot of useful Integrated tools such has syntax highlighting, auto completion, compiler and debugger, Intellisense, etc..

I really think you are mistaking those two, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not, I just thought Visual Studio Code had more features than it does. Thanks